# ffmpeg can't run both scale and hardsub

Tags: ffmpeg

my command

- Code 1

  ```
  ffmpeg -i input.mkv -vf "ass=inphut.ass" -map_metadata -1 \
  -vf scale=800:trunc(ow/a/2)*2 -vcodec libx264 -preset slow \
  -threads 2 -vprofile main -level 3.1 -vb 800K -r 25 -g 50 \
  -sc_threshold 0 -movflags faststart -acodec aac -strict -2 \
  -ab 128K output_800.mp4
  ```

When i run it, output not add hardsub.

- Code 2

  ```
  ffmpeg -i input.mkv -map_metadata -1 -vf scale=800:trunc(ow/a/2)*2 \
  -vf "ass=input.ass" -vcodec libx264 -preset slow -threads 2 \
  -vprofile main -level 3.1 -vb 800K -r 25 -g 50 -sc_threshold 0 \
  -movflags faststart -acodec aac -strict -2 -ab 128K output_800.mp4
  ```

When i change `-vf ass` below `-vf scale`, output hardsub video but scale video.

You can help me? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Combine all filtering into one instance:

```
-vf "scale=800:trunc(ow/a/2)*2,ass=input.ass"
```

Simple filters that accept one input and make one output can be joined with a comma (`,`).

See [Filtergraph Introduction](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Filtering-Introduction) for more info.

Comment: Whoa! Thank you very much! ^^